# Cannot load obj file @react-three/fiber

Tags: typescript, react-native, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am using @react-three/fiber to render a 3d Object on screen using this guide [here](https://staging.notjust.dev/blog/2023-02-17-3d-animations-in-react-native-with-threejs-nike-app).

Project: https://github.com/gagtic/three-expo

Specific file (containing the loader): https://github.com/gagtic/three-expo/blob/main/App.tsx

The problem is as soon as I load a custom obj file. The app crashes with the following dump.

```
ERROR  The above error occurred in the <Shoe> component:

tryCallOne@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:25647:16
Suspense
Suspense
ErrorBoundary@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:175842:22
FiberProvider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:173218:36
Provider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:177188:23

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.
 ERROR  Error: Could not load 1: text.indexOf is not a function. (In 'text.indexOf('\r\n')', 'text.indexOf' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in Unknown
    in FiberProvider
    in CanvasWrapper (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 ERROR  The above error occurred in the <ErrorBoundary> component:

ErrorBoundary@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:175842:22
FiberProvider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:173218:36
Provider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:177188:23

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
 ERROR  Error: Could not load 1: text.indexOf is not a function. (In 'text.indexOf('\r\n')', 'text.indexOf' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in Unknown
    in FiberProvider
    in CanvasWrapper (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 ERROR  The above error occurred in the <Shoe> component:

Shoe
Suspense
Suspense
ErrorBoundary@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:175842:22
FiberProvider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:173218:36
Provider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:177188:23

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.
 ERROR  The above error occurred in the <Shoe> component:

Shoe
Suspense
Suspense
ErrorBoundary@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:175842:22
FiberProvider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:173218:36
Provider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:177188:23

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.
 ERROR  The above error occurred in the <Shoe> component:

Shoe
Suspense
Suspense
ErrorBoundary@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:175842:22
FiberProvider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:173218:36
Provider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:177188:23

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.
 ERROR  Error: Could not load 1: text.indexOf is not a function. (In 'text.indexOf('\r\n')', 'text.indexOf' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in Unknown
    in FiberProvider
    in CanvasWrapper (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 ERROR  The above error occurred in the <ErrorBoundary> component:

ErrorBoundary@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:175842:22
FiberProvider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:173218:36
Provider@http://192.168.18.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:177188:23

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
 ERROR  Error: Could not load 1: text.indexOf is not a function. (In 'text.indexOf('\r\n')', 'text.indexOf' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in Unknown
    in FiberProvider
    in CanvasWrapper (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```